# How to send ajax request to server for updating user status "isOnline"

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, model-view-controller

I need to get call from ajax request about users whose still online in some way.
Maybe i should create some json method, that will take over this request and update db.User.IsOnline for true/false; I need to check this, 'cause when user's session ends, flag 'isOnline' doesn't switch.
I realize how it should work, but i'm bad in ajax. So please, just tell me what im supposed to do.

Comment: A good starting point would be to research an `ajax` tutorial and try use is.  If you have problems with your attempt, return here and display the relevant source code for someone to read/de-bug. Then someone can explain the problem and maybe offer you a solution.

Comment: i've been searching solution for a long time and i've seen many questions that are close to my. and there guys just like me tried to describe their problem and then other more 'accurating' guys helped them. im not trying to be rude with you, but i need to get cure for that problem as fast as i can

Comment: So you're looking for someone to write this for you? If not then as I suggested before, look for a tutorial using ajax, will take no more then 10 minutes, then try it... If you have problems return and include the relevant source code. You'll find people are willing to help those who try something first. Those who dump solutions to those who haven't tried anything are normally chasing reputation points. 52 minutes and no solution.... maybe my suggestion will speed things up and "cure" your problem much quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it the "right" (At least a better way than the one below) and you can afford using a NodeJS server , then Sockets will help you out. Due to real-time capabilities , you will be able create an event listener that when the user drops the connection for any reason , you will be informed about it and accordingly update your Database. Check out the following :

- [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/)
- [Socket.io](http://socket.io/)

Now if you can not afford a real-time solution then there are various , not so good though , workarounds. The easiest one is to create an Interval on your Client , that will send a "signal" on your server every xxx amount of time , and that signal will designate that this user is on your site. You will pretty much saying to the server "Hey i am still here". If you do not receive a signal for xxx amount of time , then the user is not online.

**Example :** 
Running a signal every 1 minute ( 60 seconds )

```
    var mySignal = setInterval(function(){
      $.ajax({url: "myServer.php?action=keepalive", success: function(result){
        console.log('all good');
      }});
    },60000);
```

Every time you receive the "keepalive" action from the user , you update your Database with the current timestamp. Now if you have one call every 60 seconds , that instantly means that if you see a timestamp in the database of a user that has not been updated for more than 60 seconds , then that user is not online.

Comment: yep, by the way, i'm already using real-time socket called signalR.
but ur solution that u've described below is that solution which i was looking for. I'll try to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

create one table for online user.
when user login at that time insert that user id to online table.
and then you check that user is your friend or not using inner join query for example that id is your friend or not if it is so fire select query for display it details whenever you want like  fill grid view.
and when user logout delete entry of that user id.so you get effect on grid view 
which of your friend is online or not.

Comment: i've implemented this feature long time ago, but it won't be working if the user just close browser or the session will end in other way

Comment: you can write the code in web.config file for hold session data after browser close.                                                                                                                        <system.web>

<sessionState cookieless="true"></sessionState>

</system.web>